# Spring EJB - WEB - ELASTICSEARCH - JPA - CRUD - BUSINESS METHOD Linkage error

Tags: ejb, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch, maven-shade-plugin, spring-config

I'm in trouble and I'm stuck in developing my project. I started to develop a hobby project that is based on spring framework, and after a while the pieces of the project were beginning to fit together.
There are two main modules, one is the EJB module, the other is the WEB module. The repositories and the core EJB beans were stored in the EJB module and they were used from the WEB module. 
Since I've used the elasticsearch before and I was completely impressed with how quickly and efficiently the data can be handled, so I thought I am going to integrate it into my hobby project.

To integrate the elasticsearch, I took the appropriate measures and added the required libraries to the project's pom file. At first glance, it seemed that everything worked well, but later it turned out that this is not the case. I created the repositories for elasticsearch tested them and I was happy, and when I tested an other feauture which was worked perfectly earlier, I was welcomed with the following exception :

> 11:41:25,213 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-33) UT005023:
>   Exception handling request to /axyz-web/test/test:
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint
>   violation: when resolving interface method "com.myproject.axyz.beans.stateless.user.UserManagementLocal.findUsers(Lorg/springframework/data/domain/Pageable;)Lorg/springframework/data/domain/Page;"
>   the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of
>   the current class,
>   com/myproject/axyz/spring/controllers/test/TestController, and the
>   class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for the
>   method's defining class,
>   com/myproject/axyz/beans/stateless/user/UserManagementLocal, have
>   different Class objects for the type
>   org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable used in the signature

First time, I thought I compiled different versions of spring-boot-data-elasticsearch both the war and ejb project (because I want to use crud repositories for elasticsearch in my web project too), and after some research I noticed my suspicions were confirmed.

Firstly, I removed the dependency from the WEB project because it depends of the EJB module, and compiled the project again then deployed it. So the spring-boot-data-elasticsearch was compiled to the EJB module.

The next message that I got was the following :

> 11:54:08,407 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 382) Context initialization failed:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEBINF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class
>   [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.config.ElasticsearchNamespaceHandler]
>   for namespace
>   [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/elasticsearch] does not
>   implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler]
>   interface.

Okay, next round, I compiled the spring-boot-data-elasticsearch into the EAR module, and set the scope to provided of the library in both module.

Like this :

### **EAR MODULE :**

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.framework.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz.xy</groupId>
        <artifactId>xyz-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz.xy</groupId>
        <artifactId>xyz-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*local.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>6</version>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <!------- 
                FINAL DESPAIR
                <modules>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
                        <bundleFileName>spring-boot-starter-elasticsearch.jar</bundleFileName>
                    </jarModule>
                </modules> 

                --------------------------->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

### **EJB MODULE :**

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-jxpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-jxpath</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- For JBOSS -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--  SPRING BOOT -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.framework.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.framework.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- dependency>
        JUST ANOTHER TRYING.......
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.framework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>   


    <!-- END  -->
</dependencies>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*local.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.framework.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

### **WEB MODULE:**

```
     .... Spring dependencies ......
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ............

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.framework.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--
        EJB MODULE 
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>MY EJB PROJECT</groupId>
        <artifactId>MY EJB PROJECT-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*local.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${test.skip}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>${shade.phase}</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                <artifactSet>
                    <includes>
                        <include>com.google.guava:guava</include>
                        <include>net.sf.trove4j:trove4j</include>
                        <include>org.mvel:mvel2</include>
                        <include>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core</include>
                        <include>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile</include>
                        <include>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml</include>
                        <include>joda-time:joda-time</include>
                        <include>io.netty:netty</include>
                        <include>com.ning:compress-lzf</include>
                    </includes>
                </artifactSet>
                <relocations>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.common</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>gnu.trove</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.common.trove</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>jsr166y</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.jsr166y</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>jsr166e</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.jsr166e</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.mvel2</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.common.mvel2</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>com.fasterxml.jackson</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.common.jackson</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.joda</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.common.joda</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.jboss.netty</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.common.netty</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>com.ning.compress</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.common.compress</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                </relocations>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/license/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/maven/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>LICENSE</exclude>
                            <exclude>NOTICE</exclude>
                            <exclude>/*.txt</exclude>
                            <exclude>build.properties</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

### **VERSION NUMBERS**

```
    <properties>
     <spring.boot.framework.version>1.5.5.RELEASE</spring.boot.framework.version>
     <spring.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
     <org.springframework.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>
```

Example connection:

```
    <elasticsearch:repositories base-package="com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.spring.elasticsearch.repositories"/>  

<elasticsearch:transport-client id="esClient" cluster-nodes="localhost:9300" />

<bean id="esConnection" class="com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.core.elasticsearch.ESConnection" init-method="init"  scope="session">
    <constructor-arg name="con" ref="container"></constructor-arg>
    <property name="client" ref="esClient"></property>
</bean>

<bean name="elasticsearchTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="client" ref="esClient"/>
</bean>
```

I also tried to exclude the spring-data-commons (because the Pageable and Page and other components are defined in that library) and compile it seperately into the WEB module, but the effects were the same, and I want to use elasticsearch and its repositories seperately in both modules.

In conclusion, if I don't compile the elasticsearch library into my WEB module, it will never be able to interpret the XML or creating the beans ( I tried the JAVA annotations too, tried newer versions, the situation was the same ), 
so I don't know what can I do to solve this problem, because linkage errors occured if the library is compiled into the WEB module.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem? Is it possible at all?